# free() crashes the code

Tags: c, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printingArr(int** arr, int rows);
void sortingEachOneOfThem(int** pArr, int rows);
void sortingTheWholeArray(int** pArr, int rows);
void bubbleSort(int* arr);
void freeArray(int **a, int m);

int main(void)
{
    int** pArr = 0;
    int numOfRows = 0;
    int sizes = 0;
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &numOfRows);
    pArr = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * numOfRows);
    if (pArr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unsuccessful malloc!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter array length for row %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d", &sizes);
        pArr[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * sizes + 1);
        if (pArr[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Unsuccessful malloc!\n");
            return 1;
        }   
        pArr[i][0] = sizes;
        for (int k = 1; k < sizes + 1; k++)
        {
            printf("Enter value for array: ");
            scanf("%d", &pArr[i][k]);
        }
    }
    printingArr(pArr, numOfRows);
    sortingEachOneOfThem(pArr, numOfRows);
    printingArr(pArr, numOfRows);
    sortingTheWholeArray(pArr, numOfRows);
    printingArr(pArr, numOfRows);


    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++)
    {
        if (pArr[i] != NULL)
        {
            free(*(pArr + i));
        }
    }
    //free(pArr);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
/*
this amazing, wonderfull piece of program prints the array given
input: int** arr, int rows
output: none
*/
void printingArr(int** arr, int rows)
{
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k <= arr[i][0]; k++)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
/*
This beautiful function sorts the whole array, but its length of rows like a pyramid
input: int** arr, int rows
output: none
*/
void sortingTheWholeArray(int** pArr, int rows)
{
    int* temp = 0;
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < rows - 1; k++)
        {
            if (pArr[k][0] > pArr[k + 1][0])
            {
                temp = pArr[k];
                pArr[k] = pArr[k + 1];
                pArr[k + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
/*
This little small function sorts every row of the array of arrays given to it
input: int** arr, int rows
output: none
*/

void sortingEachOneOfThem(int** pArr, int rows)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        bubbleSort(pArr[i]);
    }
}

/*
This little piece of a code is a bubble sort, sorts the array given to it :)
input: int* arr, int rows
output: none
*/

void bubbleSort(int* arr)
{
    int i = 1, k = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < arr[0] - 1; i++)
    {
        for (k = 1; k <= arr[0] - i; k++)
        {
            if (arr[k] > arr[k + 1])
            {
                arr[k] += arr[k + 1];
                arr[k + 1] = arr[k] - arr[k + 1];
                arr[k] -= arr[k + 1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the free at the end crashes my code, showing this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqxBG.png
the same usage of the function free() on another code worked good, but not here. I have tried running through it in step by step mode, it crashes at the first free. Dr. memory shows this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSZJr.png 
another link: https:// i.stack. imgur.com/ZX2Ne.png (paste it without the spaces in the middle, Can't post more than 2 links)
what can I do?

Comment: Post text as text itself, not as an image.

Comment: Use 2D arrays instead of pointer arrays and all such bugs will go away automatically. There is no apparent need to use an array of pointers here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
pArr[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * sizes + 1);
```

under-allocates. Adding a single byte to the size of an array of `int` makes little sense. You probably meant:

```
pArr[i] = malloc((sizes + 1) * sizeof *pArri[i]);
```

Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`, and use `sizeof` on the left-hand side.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. but why shouldn't I cast the return value of malloc()? Our teacher told us to do so, it's a convention

Comment: @Lidor You can [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169) for the reasons why. If that's your convention I guess you have to, but I can't know that when you post your code. :) Also, I'd say it's a bad convention and should be changed, for the reasons given in the linked answer.